# Module reload semantics

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
mod.py
--------
x = 1

main.py
--------
1: from importlib import reload
2: import mod as mod1
3: mod1.x = 2
4: import mod as mod2
5: print(mod2.x)
6: reload(mod2)
7: print(mod1.x)
```

Line 2 creates a `mod` object and assigns it to `mod1`. Line 4 makes an alias for `mod1` named `mod2`. Line 5 prints `2`, because `mod2` is a reference to the same object as `mod1`, that was updated by line 3. Line 6 reload mod.py using the object `mod2`, and line 7 prints `1`.

How does reload works exactly? Line 6 also updated mod1, how did it know that mod1 was an alias of mod2? Is there some mechanism to find out synonyms of a given name?

Comment: Python keeps track of already loaded modules and it won't reload them if already loaded. Then you pointed mod2 to the same object as mod1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as aliases in python, there is just [names that refer to values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). People like to call statements using the `as` keyword aliases, but `import mod as mod1` is essentially just shorthand for `import mod; mod1 = mod; del mod`.

Now to the real issue, modules are a bit of a special case, and stumbling over the peculiarities of the `import` mechanism is pretty much part of the python experience. The way modules are imported makes them behave like singletons, so every `import` statement of some module `mod` refers to the same instance of `mod`.

Whenever you try to import a module, the interpreter will first check `sys.modules`, where it will be added if it's being imported for the first time in the running session.

When you said

> Line 2 creates a `mod` object and assigns it to `mod1`.

What actually happens is

> Line 2 loads the module `mod` for this session and binds a reference of it to the name `mod1`.

---

One way you can test the identity of two names is the `is` keyword:

```py
>>> import mod as mod1
>>> import mod as mod2
>>> mod1 is mod2
True  # they are not only equal, they are the same
>>> from importlib import reload
>>> reload(mod1)
<module 'mod' from '/user/mod.py'>
>>> mod1 is mod2
True  # still the same
```

Given your initial example, it is very hard or even impossible to hold two distinct instances of a single module (they also can't be copied with `copy.copy`) - you'd better implement the functionality you have as an object instead.